# C++ Putting a string into a structure of vectors of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a problem in putting string value into a "structure of vectors of strings".
The simplest reproducible code is as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ttt {
  string name;
  unsigned int ID;
  vector<unsigned int> numList;
};

int main() {
  vector<ttt> b;
  b.reserve(3);
  b[0].ID = 1;
  b[0].numList.push_back(3);
  b[0].numList.push_back(4);
  string dd ("Desk");
  b[0].name = dd;
  cout << b[0].ID << b[0].name << b[0].numList[2] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles, but it failed to put "Desk" string into b[0].name, a structure element. Segmentation Fault arose at the spot.

I also tried below lines but all of them failed.

```
b[0].name.push_back(dd);
b[0].name += dd;
```

My compiler is GCC g++ 4.7.7 20120313,
and I used below compile command.

```
/usr/bin/g++ --std=gnu++0x -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Warray-bounds
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated, sincerely.

Comment: What does the code reproduce? A compiler error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: C'mon guys, he provided a [mcve], his compiler command line and indicated that he gets a segfault. Let's go easy on the down-voting here.

Comment: @Rakete1111 The code compiles, but segmentation fault occurs consistently.

Comment: `reserve` is very different from `resize`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors:

Assigning `b[0]` directly without calling `push_back` or without initializing it in a constructor call beforehand.

Another offending line is

```
b[0].numList[2]
```

because you only have called `push_back()` twice, and indexing is 0-based.

It would be much better to initialize the vector directly like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ttt {
  string name;
  unsigned int ID;
  vector<unsigned int> numList;
};

int main() {
  vector<ttt> b{{"Desk", 1, { 3, 4 }}};
  cout << b[0].ID << b[0].name << b[0].numList[1] << endl;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71b7d51eff82c6ce)

Answer (score 1):

You may not use the subscript operator for an empty vector to assign new values to it. Use instead `push_back` member function.

For example

```
std::vector<ttt> b;
b.reserve( 3 );

//...

b.push_back( ttt() );
b.back().ID = 1;
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error reported by Valgrind on that code is

```
==28307== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28307==    at 0x40154F: void std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::emplace_back<unsigned int>(unsigned int&&) (vector.tcc:94)
==28307==    by 0x4012D7: std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::push_back(unsigned int&&) (stl_vector.h:933)
==28307==    by 0x400F00: main (39273136.cpp:17)
```

Whilst this might seem a bit cryptic, a bit of experience suggests to check whethe the `this` argument to `push_back()` is initialised.  Looking through the code, we see:

```
  vector<ttt> b;
  b.reserve(3);
  b[0].ID = 1;
  b[0].numList.push_back(3);
```

You've told the vector to prepare to have 3 elements, but then you never add any `ttt` objects to it.  When you access `b[0]`, you're using uninitialised memory (Valgrind doesn't complain about the assignment to `b[0].ID` because the memory has been allocated and belongs to `b` - but calling `push_back` attempts to read `vector` members that may be random garbage).

The obvious solution is to `emplace_back()` (or otherwise create) the elements of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `reserve()` on a vector, it doesn't create any instances of the contained type. **It only allocates the space for the elements.**. So when you try to access these locations in the vector, you get *undefined behaviour*. You must push elements into the vector first or zero-initialize them with a call like `vector<ttt> b(6);` before trying to do any read or write on them.

Editing just the one line where you declare the vector of `ttt`s and removing the `reserve()` call fixes this program.

Also beware, because you try to access `b[0].numList[2]` , the *third* element, but you only did `push_back` for two elements.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ttt {
  string name;
  unsigned int ID;
  vector<unsigned int> numList;
};

int main() {
  vector<ttt> b(3); //create 3 zero-init elements in vector b
  b[0].ID = 1;
  b[0].numList.push_back(3);
  b[0].numList.push_back(4);
  string dd ("Desk");
  b[0].name = dd;
  cout << b[0].ID << b[0].name << b[0].numList[2] << endl;
                                             //^beware, this hasn't been initialized
  return 0;
}
```

Output: `1Desk0`